# C# using recursion with only one return

Tags: c#, recursion, factorial

I have the following recursive function

```
public int Factorial(int number_to_calculate)
{
    if (StackChanged != null)
    {
        StackChanged(new CustomEventArgs(StackValue, Result));
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);
    if (number_to_calculate == 0)
    {
        StackValue--;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        StackValue++;
        Result = (number_to_calculate * Factorial(number_to_calculate - 1));
    }

    if (StackChanged != null)
    {
        StackChanged(new CustomEventArgs(StackValue, Result));
    }
    StackValue--;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);
    return Result;
}
```

Apparently my supervisor is not ok with me having 2 returns, but wants the function to be recursive. So I only need one return. I already tried using an accumulator with goto beginning,in order to have only one return, but i need to increment StackValue every time the function calls itself and decrement it when it comes out of recursion. This way I won't know when it comes out.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like there is a strict coding standard, which isn't a bad thing. However my guess is that if your supervisor doesn't like multiple exit points a 'goto' isn't going to fly either.

Comment: yes, please dont use goto's *ever*. Also, where is Result defined?

Comment: @OnResolve: Even if `there isn't a strict coding standard`, goto should be avoided. As Gerard says.

Comment: *not ok with me having 2 returns, but wants the function to be recursive* - as it is now, the function has 2 returns *and* it is recursive. Recursion in general is not a way to replace two returns.

Comment: He is not saying he wanna replace one with the other, he is saying the function can be recursive, but can't have 2 returns.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Oh, we're in complete agreement. Although some argue a `goto` is not always bad, my response is hogwash.

Comment: @Ksempac: The "but" in his sentence implies that he wants a recursive function instead of one with two returns. Hence my pointing out that one does not exclude or require the other.

Comment: Are people really that strict with coding standards? Ours is nowhere near THAT strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (number_to_calculate == 0)
    {

        StackValue--;

        return 1;

    }...
```

do

```
if (number_to_calculate == 0)
    {

       result = 1;

    }
```

Comment: that did it. Apparently leaving StackValue--; there messes with something. Thanks

Comment: @robertpas - That would be because if you do `StackValue--` before you return `result` thus you would be decrasing `StackValue` twice not once.  Although I hope you actually UNDERSTAND the solution otherwise YOU WILL have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to make a function have a single return statement is to store the value to return in a variable, and then return it at the end.  So you would convert something like the following:

```
int myFunc() {
    if (cond)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

Into something like this:

```
int myFunc() {
    int returnValue;
    if (cond)
        returnValue = x;
    else
        returnValue = y;
    return returnValue;
}
```

This principle can be applied in general to any method, as long as you take care that when you change a return statement to variable assignment, you have conditions setup so the rest of the code is skipped.

However, a requirement like this is rather arbitrary.  It is expected in general with recursion to have multiple return statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Factorial(int number) 
        {
            int result = 1;
            StackValue++;
            if (StackChanged != null)
                StackChanged(new CustomEventArgs(StackValue, Result));

            if (number > 1) 
            {       
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time); 
                result = number * Factorial(number - 1);
            }

            StackValue--;
            if (StackChanged != null)
                StackChanged(new CustomEventArgs(StackValue, Result));

            return result;
        }
```